# is there Catalina.out property in the wrapper property

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to create a `catalina.out file` in the `tomcat/logs/`  folder through wrapper file.

Is there any property like `wrapper.java.additional=-Dcatalina.out={$tomcat}/logs/catalina.out`?

I tried to put this property in the wrapper file but not `able to get the catalina.out file` while running the tomcat `through wrapper properties file`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I truly understand, but are you asking to get the location of log directory? If so you can get with `System.getProperty("catalina.base")`